# Violin drooping when stopping strings

Tags: technique, violin

To avoid the violin drooping when I stop a string I hyperextend the metacarpophalangeal joint of the index finger to let the violin rest on the "mount of jupiter" so to speak, but this makes the "mount of jupiter" reddish after a couple of hours of playing. (Double jointedness/hypermobility in fingers makes this easy to do, but since I got red maybe it is not very good).

What can be done so that the torque of pulling the strings down can be counteracted? Or should I just let the violin rotate perhaps? It is only a few degrees after all.

Some things I believe could counteract it: sharing the pressure with thumb, moving the chin downwards with some extra force, not pulling the string all the way to the fingerboard. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is a perfect example of the more extreme side effects of trying to learn without a proper teacher.

> Some things I believe could counteract it: sharing the pressure with thumb

That is the normal way it is done. If you had a teacher he/she would have taught you that in the very lesson. In first position the violin should *rest* half way up the "V" formed by thumb and forefinger.

> moving the chin downwards with some extra force

Again, if you had a teacher then you would already know that when you start using phrases like "extra force" that you are describing something dangerous and silly. Applying "force" for any considerable period of time leads to injuries (as you have already discovered). Don't look for more ways to injure yourself.

> not pulling the string all the way to the fingerboard

If you had a teacher you would already have learned that the correct motion is not one of *pulling* the strings down to the fingerboard but of *pressing* them into the fingerboard from as directly above the strings as you can manage. Yes, the amount of downward pressure will need to vary according to the different musical notes/effects you are trying to produce.

> Any thoughts?

Do yourself a favour. Get a real flesh-and-blood teacher then he/she will fix these very basic problems in short order and you will be saved from more pain and suffering. What you are currently doing is ingraining, through much practice, habits which not only lead to injury but which take longer to eradicate the longer you persist.

Comment: I can slide without problem, so I don't know what you are talking about. I am only touching it from below when pulling the string down on the fingerboard, on the area just below the index finger on the inside.

Comment: Do you press the string on a bow and arrow as well? I think your semantical hangups are irrelevant. I already have a teacher. He thinks I should just use the thumb, but this contradicts other sources that says no tension anywhere, but without any tension the violin tilts. Also I don't think every teacher knows how to deal with double jointedness.